# Typescript, chek for null/undefined in strict mode (avoiding TS2339 and TS2358)

Tags: typescript

I'm having some troubles dealing with variables in typescript in strict mode. I want to have a variable that is lazy instantiated, but typescript compiler don't  accept my type checking. See this example:

```js
let m: Map<string, number>|undefined = undefined;

let defineMap = () => m= new Map(); // if "defineMap" runs, "m" must be a map!
defineMap(); // m MUST be a map!!!

console.log(m);// m is a map!!!

if (typeof(m) !== "undefined") {
    console.log(m.size); //error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'never'.
}

if (m!==undefined) {
    console.log(m.size); //error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'never'.
}

if(m instanceof Map<string, number>) {  //error TS2358: The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.
    console.log(m.size);
}

//THAT WORKS!
if (typeof(m) !== "undefined") {
    m = m as Map<string, number>;
    console.log(m.size);
}
```

It seems that typescript compiler ignores that my variable can be change in another context. In this example, if i swap, instantiating first and then turning it undefined in an external function, it compiles (and it gives a runtime error)

```js
let n: Map<string, number>|undefined = new Map();

let undefineMap = () => n= undefined; // if "undefineMap" runs, "m" will be undefined
undefineMap(); // m is undefined!!!

console.log(n.size);// it compiles????
```

So, what is the right way of handling with variables that can be null? Why aren't the first 3 tests valid?

Comment: This is a design limitation of TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) and the answer to the linked question for more information.  TypeScript optimistically assumes functions do not change closed-over state, so the compiler never sees that `m` is defined.  The current workaround is to disable control flow analysis for the variable in question via type assertion, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM4plN).